# Which VS tool would let me to create a grid closest to my specifications?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to create a grid of any size in pixels for an application which will let me create small icons. What I mean by pixels here is that each pixel would be a small square sized 5x5 pixels. Each little box should be clickable.

Now, which VisualStudio tool would allow me to create such grid automatically from user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant to say control instead of tool you could create a TableLayoutPanel and fill it with Buttons or PictureBoxes.  You could dynamically set the number of rows and columns and add objects to the panel.

However, unless your app is going to be very small (visually) you will end up creating many controls which will have an impact on performance.  In this case the best idea is to follow the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999792/display-hundreds-images-dynamically) and perform the drawing and hit testing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Source Editor. Start programming.

Sorry, you dont ask about .NET classes, you ask explicitly about tools.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Please explain.